# When do we want to inject a class instead of instance?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Since typically classes are constructed by providing 0 or more initial parameters, it sounds nature to use instance injection.

When do we want to bind a class to a subclass instead of an instance of the subclass?

Comment: A class is an instance of java.lang.Class so even infecting a class would be instance injection. You'd inject that whenever you need to configure a class instance for reflection. But it doesn't happen very often. Why are you asking?

Comment: And how does your question related to Guice?  You'd bind (inject) a class if it takes an argument of that type.  Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind a class, you delegate responsibility for resolving dependencies to Guice, while instance injection puts that on you; if, for example, you use instance injection for a `Foo` that requires a `Bar`, you are now responsible for manually injecting the `Bar`, which basically defeats much of the point of using Guice.

[From the Guice docs on instance injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InstanceBindings) (emphasis added)

> You can bind a type to a specific instance of that type. **This is
>   usually only useful only for objects that don't have dependencies of
>   their own, such as value objects**:`

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean if I have a class Foo that requires a Bar, and a Bar requires an integer. What I need to do is bind Foo with Bar, and bind Bar with integer, say 3, and Guice will construct Foo for me?